# Java: Importing Library to Multiple Classes

Tags: java, oop, import, libraries

I've been searching for an answer on ***StackOverflow*** and ***Google***. I've done my legwork before asking.

If I'm importing a library into a ***Java*** program and want it available in the different classes, do I need to import it to each one manually or is there some way to do this globally?

So far I've been doing what I show below as an example, but it feels a bit 'clunky' and not optimal:

MainProgram:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Gets getIn = new Gets();

        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String fromKey = getIn.first(keyboard);
        System.out.println(fromKey);
    }
}
```

Gets.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gets
{
    public String first(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        String result = keyboard.nextLine();
        return result;
    }
}
```

As stated above this feels clunky.

Is there any way to have this work with just having to import the libraries into the ***MainProgram.java*** file and have them imported to each class that is called (obviously the type would still need to be mentioned in the methods, but that's minor)?

I can see problems arising if the classes are then used in another program that doesn't import the same libraries, however that seems minor with proper commenting.

Answer (score 4):

You have to import it for every class file.

Notice the 'file': you can have multiple classes in one file but you'll only have to import once.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean here, the 'file' you are referring to is the individual class files I've got?

Comment: I guess he is meaning that your Gets would be a private class and would reside in the same java file as your MainProgram class

Comment: A .java file can only have 1 public class. But it can have multiple classes without an accessor (`class X`) or private classes (`private class Y`), etc. You don't have to import for each of these classes if they're in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import to every class.

However, doing this with a modern ***IDE*** like ***Eclipse*** is pretty simple, such that I barely notice it.

Just start typing the class name in the method/declaration/wherever you're using it, and it should pop up an auto-complete-type-thingey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to force it) that'll let you choose which import you want.

Comment: I want to upvote this because you are trying to add value. But much of this post (the questions) should be comments. And more detail is needed. LMK if you can clean it and add some detail. I'd be glad to vote up.

Comment: Thanks, will look into Eclipse!  I'm just using vi at the moment while learning, but guessing an IDE like Eclipse would be helpful at this point.

Comment: @DaveA I tweaked it some

Comment: `thingey ` - too technical!

Comment: Much better. I wish I could've given it +4 cause now I believe it's the best answer for OP.

Comment: @DaveA well those button things cool, now you're just showing off ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to import it for every class. Like Taylor said, using eclipse makes it alot easier.  A shortcut in eclipse would be to write out the Scanner code line and when you get that read underline error, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> for 'organize imports'. This will automatically type in the import for you at the top of file in an organized alphabetized way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You have to import it for every class that you want to use those libries

Answer (score 0):

As others are saying, `You have to import it for every class that you want to use those libraries`,
however you may want to look at some inheritance (super-class) that will encapsulate this logic for you.

E.g. `MyScanner extends Scanner`

with MyScanner being used in all of your classes and it having methods that return only the results

E.g `List<String> getAllLines ();`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look more into this aspect of encapsulation!